# ckeditor instant load after append

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am using this way to load ckeditor in my php page using class method:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor0_en"><?=$name;?>hellohello</textarea>
```

it works fine for the initial textarea. Then, I tried to append more textarea with the same class after clicking a button, however, this time, I only can append a bare textarea without loaded with ckeditor.

Would there be anyway that I can load the ckeditor appearance after appending? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After appending a textarea use

```
CKEDITOR.replace(element);
```

it replaces a textarea or a DOM element (DIV) with a CKEditor instance.

[See Official Documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.replace)